# ps script not taking in parameters

Tags: powershell

I am trying to convert a program from dos to powershell which executes an external program with some parameters and arguments in it.  Here's the DOS script.

Here's the DOS script with parameters.

```
.\dtllst CHEETAH config=.\dbmover_CHEETAH.cfg >> .\listener_CHEETAH.txt
```

and here's the PS code.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
      [string] $listener
    ,  [string] $dbmover
    , [string] $appname

)

& "$pwd\dtllst.exe" "$listener" , "config=$config" | out-file -FilePath "$outfile" -append
```

What I noticed was ps script was not using the config file (dbmover_CHEETAH.cfg) during the execution.But rather using the default dbmover file which is stored in the present working directory. Where as the DOS program is using the file defined in the config parameter.

Comment: `$config` and `$outfile` don't seem to be defined anywhere.

Comment: I did define the paramter although I have not pasted them on this post.

Comment: $pwd = "C:\PowerExchange"
$var  = ($dbmover).Split(".")[0]

$config="$pwd\$dbmover"

$outfile="$pwd\$appname\Start\$var"

Comment: if `$config` is define as `$config="$pwd\$dbmover" `, then surely it should be using _"...using the default dbmover file which is stored in the present working directory..."_ as you say.